Is there a non-unimodular group which is not contained in a unimodular group?
The examples I know of non-unimodular (locally compact second countable) groups arise as subgroups the general linear group (e.g. the affine linear group). I was wondering whether there is an example of one which is not linear, or more generally, one which is not contained in a unimodular group.

Do you assume local compactness?

Yes, everything is in terms of the Haar measure. I'll make it explicit

This is what I thought.
